# Windows 7 does not receive Encapsulated Security Payload (ESP) packet on RAW socket

Tags: windows, sockets, networking, raw-sockets

I am trying to use recvfrom() function to receive Encapsulated Security Payload or ESP (IP protocol number = 50) packets on a raw socket. Unfortunately it is not working in windows 7. I would like to mention here that I can receive generic routing encapsulation (GRE) packets on a raw socket by just setting the IP protocol number to 47. And the socket smoothly works and receives GRE packets. But it fails on receiving ESP packets.

I should also mention that I have disabled my firewall services and windows' two default IPSec services viz. 1. IKE and AuthIP IPsec keying modules and 2. IPsec policy agent. I think by some reason windows is not sending the ESP packet to the upper layer.

Can anyone help me? Here is my program.

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Link with ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int main()
{

    int iResult = 0;

    WSADATA wsaData;

    SOCKET RecvSocket;
    sockaddr_in RecvAddr;

    unsigned short Port = 27015;

    char RecvBuf[1024];
    int BufLen = 1024;

    sockaddr_in SenderAddr;
    int SenderAddrSize = sizeof (SenderAddr);

    //-----------------------------------------------
    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"WSAStartup failed with error %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------
    // Create a receiver socket to receive datagrams
    RecvSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 50);
    if (RecvSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        wprintf(L"socket failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------
    // Bind the socket to any address and the specified port.
    RecvAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    RecvAddr.sin_port = htons(Port);
    RecvAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    iResult = bind(RecvSocket, (SOCKADDR *) & RecvAddr, sizeof (RecvAddr));
    if (iResult != 0) {
        wprintf(L"bind failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------
    // Call the recvfrom function to receive datagrams
    // on the bound socket.
    wprintf(L"Receiving datagrams...\n");
    iResult = recvfrom(RecvSocket,
                       RecvBuf, BufLen, 0, (SOCKADDR *) & SenderAddr, &SenderAddrSize);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"recvfrom failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------
    // Close the socket when finished receiving datagrams
    printf("\n\nBufLen = %d\n\n", BufLen);
    wprintf(L"Finished receiving. Closing socket.\n");
    iResult = closesocket(RecvSocket);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"closesocket failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------
    // Clean up and exit.
    wprintf(L"Exiting.\n");
    Sleep(60000);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you confirm that the received packet has the expected header by looking at it with a sniffer (NetMon or Wireshark) ?

Comment: Yes, I have checked it in Wireshark. The received packet is completely correct along with the IP header.